# How to remove the additional numbers added to the row names when they are the same across tables when using print.xtableList

Tags: r, xtable

The row name got changed (added some numbers to differentiate them) when printing using `print.xtableList`.

Note the `lgw.v1` in the second tabular, it should be `lgw.v`

Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

```
% latex table generated in R 3.4.4 by xtable 1.8-4 package
% Tue Oct 29 15:31:10 2019
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}

\multicolumn{6}{l}{kappa=1.0}\\ 
\hline
 & mean & sd & median & min & max \\\hline

lgw.v & 8.1 & 0.68 & 8.13 & -7.73 & 22.56 \\ 
  lge.v & 20.87 & 4.44 & 20.89 & 4.17 & 40.18 \\ 
  atom.v & 21.96 & 4.22 & 21.93 & 6.53 & 40.30 \\ 
  gg.v & 21.74 & 4.34 & 21.72 & 5.01 & 40.18 \\ 
  rand.v & -1.12 & 6.22 & -0.90 & -28.00 & 21.40 \\ 
   \hline\\ 
\multicolumn{6}{l}{kappa=1.1}\\ 
\hline
 & mean & sd & median & min & max \\\hline
lgw.v1 & 11.33 & 3.58 & 11.31 & -7.54 & 27.37 \\ 
  lge.v1 & 25.07 & 4.40 & 25.16 & 6.91 & 42.36 \\ 
  atom.v1 & 26.62 & 3.94 & 26.68 & 8.30 & 42.54 \\ 
  gg.v1 & 26.45 & 3.99 & 26.51 & 10.34 & 42.36 \\ 
  rand.v1 & 3.53 & 5.57 & 3.77 & -24.83 & 22.89 \\ 
   \hline\\ 
\multicolumn{6}{l}{kappa=1.2}\\ 
\hline
 & mean & sd & median & min & max \\\hline
lgw.v2 & 15.21 & 3.45 & 15.22 & 0.96 & 29.04 \\ 
  lge.v2 & 28.95 & 4.20 & 29.06 & 8.38 & 45.49 \\ 
  atom.v2 & 30.60 & 3.61 & 30.64 & 9.96 & 45.77 \\ 
  gg.v2 & 30.48 & 3.64 & 30.51 & 16.46 & 45.81 \\ 
  rand.v2 & 6.89 & 4.98 & 7.03 & -18.67 & 26.96 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{comparison of kappa value for} 
\label{tab::kappa-v}
\end{table}


############################################# the r code


vlist = list()

for (i in c(1:5)) {
  vlist[[i]] =  ll[[i]][c(1:nMethods),]

}

sNames = split(pNames, seq(nrow(pNames)))

attr(vlist, "subheadings") <- as.list(sNames)

capS = paste0("comparison of kappa value for")

xList <- xtableList(vlist, caption = capS, label = "tab::kappa-v",
                    align = NULL, digits = NULL, display = NULL)
print.xtableList(xList, colnames.format = "multiple", rotate.rownames = FALSE ,  rotate.colnames=FALSE)
```

I know there is a "sanitize.rownames.function". But is there a parameter that can control that? I have tried several but does not work.

Comment: Could you please give us the orginal object where your table come from. Indeed it will help us to answer your question.

Comment: Even better than the original object would be a *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: But I think the rowname de-duplication isn't done by `xtable` - row names of a data frame *must* be unique. `x = mtcars[c(1, 1), 1:2]`, look at `x` - already deduplicated. Try to fix it manually, `row.names(x) = c("a", "a")` - get an error: `duplicate row.names are not allowed`. Your best bet may be to put the values you want in the first column and not print row names at all.